# Brand new grill pan was seasoned but food taste rancid/metallic?

Tags: seasoning

Bought new cast iron grill pan from Bed Bath etc and seasoned it per videos on FB. Then used for first time tonight and something is off. Grilled asparagus tasted rancid or metallic and the pan smoked alot. Prior to using the pan it seemed sticky and shiny. Thinking maybe a failed seasoning due to too much oil? Is this right and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably used too much oil when seasoning and maybe the wrong kind of oil. When seasoning you want the thinnest layer of oil possible, and you want to season several times. I use cold-pressed flaxseed oil and season my pans five times using this method:

1. thoroughly clean and dry the pan. some pans (like carbon steel) come with a layer of wax to protect them from rust and this must be removed before seasoning. one manufacturer suggests cooking potato skins, salt, and oil with constant stirring for 15 minutes, then a second time to remove this. do your best to get the pan prepped properly before seasoning.
2. put a small amount of flaxseed oil on a paper towel and coat the entire pan, inside and out including the handle. then use a second, dry paper towel to remove the oil. there will be a very thin layer left. you want to get it as dry as possible. there will still be a micro layer of residual oil left on the pan after this step even if it seems to be too dry. it's not.
3. crank your oven to 550°F and let it heat up fully. then turn the pan upside down (so any oil, of which there should be none, will drip out) and leave in for an hour. then turn off the oven and let it cool compeletely.
4. repeat steps 2-3 five times.
5. depending on the pan you may want to hold off cooking eggs or things that stick easily until you have used the pan for a while.

To answer your question of how to fix:
1. Clean your pan again using soap and steel wool and get off all your existing cooked oil. Dry thoroughly.
2. Follow seasoning steps above.

Answer (score 0):

"Sticky" sounds like the seasoning didn't work.

I've struggled with seasoning a cast-iron pan, until I found [this technique](https://fieldcompany.com/pages/how-to-season-cast-iron-pan-skillet).

Use grapeseed oil.

Clean out any sticky residue from the pan. In desperation, I ran my pan through the oven's self-cleaning cycle. Amazing how much ash dropped out from the bad seasoning that I had done. YMMV.

Heat the oven to 200 degrees F. Put the pan in the oven, upside down, for ten minutes. Take the pan out of the oven, and turn the temperature up to 300 degrees F.

Drizzle a bit of oil on the bottom of the pan, and spread it with a paper towel. Turn the pan over, drizzle a bit of oil into the pan, and spread it with a paper towel. In both cases, the paper towel will soak up most of the oil. That's a good thing. You want just enough to **lightly** coat the pan.

Put the pan into the 300 degree the oven for ten minutes. Take it out, and turn the temperature up to 400 degrees F.

Use a paper towel to remove the excess oil from the pan. Yes, there will be some, even though you removed the excess oil when you applied it.

Put the pan into the 400 degree oven for an hour. Let it cool.

Repeat until done. I've gone through three cycles with my 10-inch frying pan, and it's really good. But I might do one more.